# Google Chrome developer tools console log level buttons are gone

Tags: google-chrome, console, developer-tools

I don't know why it is showing the console menu like this.
[image]

If I hide the settings it will display[image]

when I click on the error dropdown[image]

This is how I want it to look like
[image]

Comment: Can you click on the "Errors" dropdown?

Comment: just updated the post see the new picture.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this is a browser update with Chrome DevTools in v58 https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/devtools-release-notes#console

Comment: Thank you. I hope they'll bring back the log level buttons

Comment: Me too! How was it broken the way it was?  It seems like they tried to make it simpler.  Since when do developers need "simpler"?

Answer (score 0):

Use Chromium builds, at least that still has the filter options.