# How to filter Chrome console logs in Chrome version 58

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

Hi I just want to filter out console warnings and errors just to see **ONLY** logs. 
It is very easy to do this when you can click the little filter button and select what type of message you want to see.

However, I find out that filter button is **GONE** in dev console Chrome version 58 !!!

Look the top left corner. There used to have a little fitler shaped button with clear button.

[image]

Comment: you can click the 'Verbose' dropdown beside that and see only warning or errors

Comment: but how do you see only logs? no warnings nor errors

Comment: you select 'info' then you will see only logs

Comment: Nope, you can try yourself, 'info' level will let you see log, warning, and error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Chrome developer tools console log level buttons are gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43798306/google-chrome-developer-tools-console-log-level-buttons-are-gone)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out since Chrome 58, Chrome dev has adapted some sort of "conservative log model" stuff, which basically means you can't just filter out warnings and errors like it used to be.

I'm using firefox now.